# Is there a naming convention for methods implemented with yield return?

Tags: c#

I've been writing myself some utils involving collections when I remembered the existence of the `yield return` statement.

Then I wondered, is there an established naming convention for methods that use `yield return` or methods that return `Enumerable<T>`?

Comment: In one word: No. Some methods use `Enumerate`(like `Directory.EnumerateFiles`).

Comment: No. Use your own convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually functions change name when the output differs; for instance, Async suffix for asynchronous methods, because the return expectation is much different.  With yield, the return output is still the same; an enumerble is still returned to the caller.

If you want to create a convention, go ahead and do it; generally there isn't a naming convention assigned.  But most conventions are usually organization-based anyway; if you think there is a necessity, go ahead and do it.